# Alternative forms of metacentric height based stability condition

Tags: fluid-dynamics, buoyancy, oceanography

For a floating body is stable condition Archimedes principle of buoyancy will be obeyed. where $M_{b}$ and $M_{w}$ are mass of the total body and mass of the emerged water.
$$M_{b}=M_{w}$$
Tilting it with an angle $\theta$ will restore back to the origination position if the body satisfies the conditions for the metacentric height equation. Where $GM$ is the straight line distance between center of gravity of the body and Metacenter
$$GM >= 0$$

I find calculation of $GM$ to be very difficult for composite bodies.So I am looking for some alternative forms.

The metacentric height intuitively looks like a generalization of Archimedes principle, however as the second one requires knowledge about its shape mathematically it is not trivial to find a connection between them. If the floating body is restored to its original position after a tilt of angle $\theta$ it implies the body is still floating even after the tilt.

Q1: If a body satisfies metacentric height based equation on $\theta$ tilt then is the Archimedes principle based buoyancy equation (on ultilted condition) redundant and implicitly satisfied ?

Q2: How can the scenario be expressed in terms of archimedis principle after the body is tilted ? (May be the equality turns into an inequility)

Q3: If the body satisfies Archimedes principle twice once before the tilt and then again after the theta tilt can we consider the metacentric height based equation to be implicitly satisfied irrespective of the shape of the body ?

Q4: When we tilt do we measure the angle $\theta$ on the point where the vertical axis intersects with the fluid surface plane ? or w.r.t. the metacenter ?

Q5: If the tilt $\theta$ is measured w.r.t. a different point than metacenter then the picture looks like the stabilizing oscilation is applied on a different point than the destabilazing tilt is applied to. So there should be a drag. So are there two actions working on two different point ?